# Beginner java code not working (countdown).. why?

Tags: java

Thank for taking the time to look and help.
I'm simply trying to get my integer value to hit 1 by going down from 10 by 1. 
When I do this it works:

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int value = 10;
        while (value > 0)
        {
            System.out.println(value);
            value --;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I make it:

```
while (value > 0)
{
    System.out.println(value);
    value - 1;
```

It does not work...
Why is this?

Comment: `value - 1` doesn't assign the result of the subtraction anywhere. it's just throwing the value away. you want `value = value - 1`

Comment: Might I also suggest review.stackexchange.com they might be a better fit for your questions?

Comment: Please consider doing some basic Java tutorials here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Answer (score 4):

You aren't storing the new outcome for `value` anywhere. It should be

```
while(value > 0){
   System.out.println(value);
   value = value -1; // equivalent to value--
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While you decrease the value by one, you are not assign this number to any variable.

You can replace it with `value = value - 1;` or `value -= 1.`